# Error Code: 1022. Can't write; duplicate key in table x - While Restoring Database Backup

Tags: database, backup

I am trying to restore a database backup to my local project, however I'm getting this error. I searched and found out that it is because I am trying to set an existing constraint name when I run the backup file. But i don't know how to solve it. I tried to rename the constraints, but there are a loooot of it and it's impossible to rename all of them, one by one. Can anyone help me?

One piece of my code is this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `apscatalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;

CREATE TABLE `apscatalog_product_entity_media_gallery` (
  `value_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Value ID',
  `attribute_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Attribute ID',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Value',
  PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_MEDIA_GALLERY_ATTRIBUTE_ID` (`attribute_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_MEDIA_GALLERY_ENTITY_ID` (`entity_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `apseav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `apscatalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Media Gallery Attribute Backend Table';
```